# Message Queue - Solaris10 - Could not open

Tags: c, ipc, solaris, message-queue

I want to write 2 programs that communicate with a message queue!

### common.h

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

#define QUEUE_NAME "/zq1"
#define MAX_SIZE 100
#define MSG_STOP "quit"

#endif
```

### server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "common.h"

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char buf[MAX_SIZE];
    int size=0;
    mqd_t mq;
    int open_flags= O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_EXCL;



mq=mq_open(QUEUE_NAME, open_flags, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG, NULL);

if(mq ==(mqd_t)-1)
{
    perror("Message Queue Open Failed");
    return 1;
}


/* INPUT */
printf("Exit with 'quit' \n\n");
for(;;)
{
    printf("Eingabe:");
    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
    size=strlen(buf);
    buf[size-1]=0;

    if(mq_send(mq,buf,strlen(buf),0)<0)
    {
        perror("Failure mq_send()");
    }
    if(strcmp(buf,MSG_STOP)==0) break;
}
/*
for(;;)
{
    memset(&buf,0,sizeof(buf));
    mq_receive(mq,buf,MAX_SIZE,NULL);
    printf("%s ",buf);
    if(strcmp(buf,MSG_STOP)==0) break;
}
*/
mq_close(mq);
//  mq_unlink(QUEUE_NAME);

return 0;
}
```

i could read and write, but if i want to open the mq with the client:
"No such file or directory"

The server does not creat a file, but why?

### client

```
#include <mqueue.h>
#include "common.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main()
{
mqd_t mq;
char buf[MAX_SIZE];
ssize_t bytes_read;

mq=mq_open(QUEUE_NAME,O_RDWR);
if((mqd_t)-1 == mq)
{
    perror("Error mq_open()");
    return 1;
}

for(;;)
{
    bytes_read=mq_receive(mq,buf,MAX_SIZE,NULL);
            if(bytes_read == -1) perror("Error Read")
    printf("inhalt:%s",buf);
    if(strncmp(buf,MSG_STOP,strlen(MSG_STOP))==0)
        break;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the complete code?

Answer (score 1):

i found it, i wrote

```
if((mqd_t)-1 != mq)
```

I'am sorry!

But the problem ist still the same! client doesn't get any messages

Error: Message too long

The size of MAX_SIZE was too short, i raised it up to 1024 and it works well!

Comment: In that case you would get `Error mq_open(): Success` in the client right?